# Passing argument to command line to connect and after connection established pass another argument in same command

Tags: c#

I have `Server - Client` application, from client side I am passing Server IP address as first  argument and after the connection established i want to pass another argument.

How to pass multiple arguments to a newly created process in C#?

Also which class (Process or ProcessStartInfo or MyProcess) in should I use in executing a program, with the condition of passing multiple arguments to the newly created/executed process?

```
Process.Start( "program.exe");
```

Comment: Yes it is possible to `archieve` that provided you make a good question with clear senctences and stop of `connecting` sentences to each other and use some dots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass arguments to a process use this overload simply:

```
   Process.Start("cmd.exe", "start notepad");
```

This starts the command line and passes to it the command `start notepad` as an argument.